# NodeJS / MariaDB Connector -- createConnection() does not return proper connection object

Tags: mysql, node.js, mariadb

Node.js is installed in the following version on my Ubuntu 18/04 machine:

```
  node -v
  v14.16.0
```

The following modules are installed:

```
  sudo npm list -g --depth=0
  /usr/lib
  ├── mariadb@2.5.3
  └── npm@6.14.11
```

The required package

The relevant code in my app file maria.js looks like this:

```
const mariadb = require('mariadb');
let conn = mariadb.createConnection({
     host: 'localhost', 
     database: 'db1',
     user:'dbuser1', 
     password: 'dbpwd',
     port: 3306
});

conn.connect(function(err){
  if(err){
    console.log('Database connection error');
  }else{
    console.log('Database connection successful');
  }
});
```

The required package 'mariadb' is satisfied and createConnection() does not return an error.
However, getting to the connect() statement, NodeJS returns the following:

```
conn.connect(function(err){
     ^

TypeError: conn.connect is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/juerg/bin/node/maria.js:12:6)
```

So looks like that createConnection() returns an empty JS object. Any other Connection class method won't work either, and I can't discover an error in this short code fragment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mariadb.createConnection` [returns a promise](https://github.com/mariadb-corporation/mariadb-connector-nodejs/blob/41d3926b1deed2fe10e601d13cd954a7f1654a66/lib/connection.js#L56) so you would have to `await` for it to return the connection, like:

```
let conn = await mariadb.createConnection({
     host: 'localhost', 
     database: 'db1',
     user:'dbuser1', 
     password: 'dbpwd',
     port: 3306
});
```

Also there might not be a need to call `conn.connect()` separately since it is already done in `createConnection`: [Source Code](https://github.com/mariadb-corporation/mariadb-connector-nodejs/blob/41d3926b1deed2fe10e601d13cd954a7f1654a66/promise.js#L20)

Or if you do not want to make your function async then you can do something like:

```
mariadb.createConnection({
     host: 'localhost', 
     database: 'db1',
     user:'dbuser1', 
     password: 'dbpwd',
     port: 3306
}).then((conn) => {
     // Do here what you want to do with MySQL connection...
});
```

Comment: This does not work, unfortunately:

let conn = await mariadb.createConnection({
           ^^^^^
SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

Also, none of the examples uses that keyword.

Comment: You will have to make the calling function `async` or you can use promise (updated the original answer).

Comment: Thanks Ismail, both solutions solved my problem. I wished the numerous code samples out there would have stressed out the Promise point clearer. But now I hope your solution helps other NodeJS newbies..

Comment: Thanks yumeier, glad that I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

As per the [MariaDB connector documentation](https://github.com/mariadb-corporation/mariadb-connector-nodejs/blob/master/documentation/callback-api.md) there are two available API's, Promise and Callback, Promise is the default API which you require and use in the following manner.

```
const mariadb = require("mariadb");
mariadb.createConnection({
     host: 'localhost', 
     database: 'database',
     user:'username', 
     password: 'password',
     port: 3306
}).then(conn => {
    // Execute a query/do whatever you need with the connection object here.
});
```

Alternatively, you can use the Callback API (which to note, is for compatibility with the mysql and mysql2 modules) by modifiyig the require statement and then connecting as follows:

```
const mariadb = require("mariadb/callback");
const conn = mariadb.createConnection({
     host: 'localhost', 
     database: 'database',
     user:'username', 
     password: 'password',
     port: 3306
});
conn.connect(err => {
    if (err) return console.log("Failed to connect");
    console.log(`Successfully connected to mariadb server: ${conn.serverVersion()}`);
});

// Execute a query/do whatever you need with the connection object here.
```